# Restored Test DNN Website on localhost keeps redirecting to Test URL

Tags: iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I restored the Test DNN Website and Database on local machine but still it is redirecting to Test Url.

Please help me run the DNN Website on Local Machine.

I change the PortalAlias, PortalSettings, webconfig pointing to Local Database. But still not resolved.

following message appears, when I enter my email for Login:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX-XXXX-44e7-XXXX-7de5c833XXXX/oauth2/authorize?scope=email&client_id=3b8a260d-PPPP-420a-PPPP-efd8cad8XXXX&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fuattest.tio.com%2fLogin&state=Azure&response_type=code&login_hint=arsalan.amin@tio.com

https%3a%2f%2fdnn.localhost.com
https%3a%2f%2fuattest.tio.com
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-420a-XXXX-efd8cadPPPPP'.

Answer (score 0):

*Configuration in .net framework generally we only need to modify the redirecturl.*

**Make sure the redirecturl in project same as azure portal, your issue should be solved.**

[image]

---

#### Solution:

1. After you restored website, please check the RedirectUrl.
2. Click `App registrations`, and check `Authentication->Platform configurations->Redirect URIs`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I add the Redirect Url in App Registration but following message appears:

Comment: @ArsalanAmin What the url should be like ?

Comment: @ArsalanAmin `https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX-XXXX-44e7-XXXX-7de5c833XXXX/oauth2/authorize?scope=email&client_id=3b8a260d-PPPP-420a-PPPP-efd8cad8XXXX&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fuattest.tio.com%2fLogin&state=Azure&response_type=code&login_hint=arsalan.amin@tio.com`, I mean this.

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Can you show me the screenshot like me, I want to confirm your redirect urls.

Comment: I add the Redirect Url in App Registration but following message appears:                                  
https://dnn.localhost.com/Login?ode=0.AUIAu6IqMt6w50S8uX3l.....&state=Azure&session_state=4a20e959-b7b1-464f-877e-beeca9459841 Hmmm… can't reach this pagednn.localhost.com refused to connect.
Try:

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Why you don't use `https://localhost:port` ? Can you access https://dnn.localhost.com in your pc ?

Comment: I am able to access the dnn.localhost.com from the PC. Would you please guide me which port I have to use ? 4024 is Ok ?

Comment: I am not able to post the image here. But please have a look to following url:

Comment: @ArsalanAmin No, pls delete it, and just keep `https://uattest.tio.com/...` in your portal. And you also need to check the web.cofig, it also should be `https://uattest.tio.com`.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/914cy9qtm7dwjp5/DNN_DEV.png/file

Comment: @ArsalanAmin OkOk,np.

Comment: @ArsalanAmin You just have only one app registration right ? And now you want use `https://dnn.localhost.com/login` for redirect url, right ?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/1aeosx8f2vrpvg5/dnn.localhost.com_is_working_from_local_machine.png/file

Comment: Yeap,  only one app registration with redirect url to my local machine i.e https://dnn.localhost.com/login

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Now, I saw three urls, which one you want to be redirect url ?(1.https://uattest.tio.com/Login  2. https://dnn.localhost.com/login 3. https://dev....com/login)

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Don't worry, I will help you solve the issue.

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Ok, Can you show your web.config, you can use this site to upload pic. https://imgur.com/upload

Comment: Yeap, I am uploading the Webconfig. But I will replace the credentials with XXX. Its Ok ?

Comment: @ArsalanAmin Sure

Comment: @ArsalanAmin I just want to check your redirect url.

Comment: This is the Webconfig file Link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/77qjevdk7562xon/web.config/file

Comment: @ArsalanAmin I can't find clientid, tenantid... Which palce they are in your program ?

Comment: Actually, there is API which authentication B2B

Comment: Would you share the email, I will send you the Zoom invite and share the screen. Its Ok ?

Comment: @ArsalanAmin I'm afraid not, I should be offline in a while, I will check this case tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, no worries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason for help, Issue resolved now, DNN Site is working on Local Host.

Comment: @ArsalanAmin You can post your solution as answer, it will help more forum users.